# Merge Sort on a Linked List Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to apply a merge sort onto a linked list, i have a general idea of what i'm doing however the code when run fails my simple jUnit tests. I'm unsure what part went wrong and cannot seem to work out what needs to be fixed.
Any help is appreciated and explanations to help for future times even more so.

```
class musicNode {
    String track;  // The name of the track
    int played= 0; // The number of times played
    int shuffleTag= 0;
    musicNode next;

public musicNode() {        // Construct an empty list.
    next = null;
}
public musicNode(String t) {
    track = t; next = null;
}
public musicNode(String t, musicNode ptr) {
    track = t; next = ptr;
}

 public boolean LTTrack(musicNode x) {   // Compares tracks according to alphabetical order on strings
     if (this.track.compareTo(x.track)<=0) return true;
     else return false;
 }

 public boolean LTPlayed(musicNode x) {   // Compares according to the played field.
     if (this.played <= x.played) return true;
     else return false;
 }

 public boolean LTTag(musicNode x) {   // Compares according to the shuffle tag.
     if (this.shuffleTag <= x.shuffleTag) return true;
     else return false;
 }

};


public class MusicPlayer {
    protected musicNode head = null; // Pointer to the top of the list.
    int length=0;   // the number of nodes in the list. 

void sortTrack() {
    musicNode main = this.head;
    mergeSort(main);
}

public musicNode mergeSort(musicNode a) {
    if (a == null || a.next == null)
        return a;

    musicNode nodeLeft = a;
    musicNode nodeRight = a.next;

    while((nodeRight != null) && (nodeRight.next != null)){
        a = a.next;
        nodeRight = (nodeRight.next).next;
    }
    nodeRight = a.next;
    a.next = null;

    return merge(mergeSort(nodeLeft), mergeSort(nodeRight));
}

public musicNode merge(musicNode leftStart, musicNode rightStart){
    musicNode temp = new musicNode();
    musicNode head = temp;
    musicNode c = head;
    while ((leftStart != null) && (rightStart != null)) 
    {
        if (leftStart.track.compareTo(rightStart.track) <= 0){
            c.next = leftStart;
            c = leftStart;
            leftStart = leftStart.next;
        } else {
            c.next = rightStart;
            c = rightStart;
            rightStart = rightStart.next;
        }
    }
    c.next = (leftStart == null) ? rightStart : leftStart;
    return head.next;
 }
```

This is the jUnit tests i'm running on it for testing purposes

```
@Test
public void testSortMixed() {   
    MusicPlayer trackList= new MusicPlayer();
    trackList.insertTrack("d");
    trackList.insertTrack("b");
    trackList.insertTrack("e");
    trackList.insertTrack("a");
    trackList.insertTrack("c");

    MusicPlayer trackListTwo= new MusicPlayer();
    trackListTwo.insertTrack("e");
    trackListTwo.insertTrack("d");
    trackListTwo.insertTrack("c");
    trackListTwo.insertTrack("b");
    trackListTwo.insertTrack("a");

    trackList.sortTrack();
    musicNode tmp= trackList.head;
    musicNode tmp2= trackListTwo.head;
    for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){
        assertEquals(tmp2.track, tmp.track);
        tmp2= tmp2.next;
        tmp=tmp.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Merge sort](https://youtu.be/XaqR3G_NVoo) :D I think you should tell us if this is homework (if not what is wrong with JDK lists)

Comment: It is work, but I've spent my day going at this and still can't get it so I've come on here to look for assistance. Is there anything wrong with that?